# Login form, django and react send data with post method but I cant get it in the server

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working on a web application using Django and React. I'm specifically facing an issue with handling form data. I have created a login form in my React application, and when I submit the form, I'm sending the form data to the server. However, on the server side (using Django), I'm having trouble receiving and processing the form data correctly.

After submitting the form, I'm expecting to receive the form data on the server and perform some authentication logic. But when I try to access the received data on the server, I'm getting an empty dictionary instead of the expected form data.

I have checked my client-side code and ensured that the form data is being sent correctly from the React application. However, I'm not sure why the server is not able to receive and process the data properly.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could provide guidance or suggestions on how to properly handle and receive form data on the server side using Django. If you have any experience with Django and React and have encountered a similar issue before, your insights would be invaluable. Thank you in advance for any help or advice you can provide!"

ShareRetry

this is my views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def customer_login(request):
  
    print(request.POST)
    msg={
        'bool':True,
        "post":request.POST
    }
 
    return JsonResponse(msg)
```

Login.jsx

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import {  Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios'
function Login() {
    const baseurl='http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        username: '',
        password: ''
      });

    
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
            ...prevFormData,
            [name]: value
        }));
    };  
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        // Perform login logic here
        console.log('username:', formData.username);
        console.log('Password:', formData.password);
    
        // Reset form fields


        axios.post(baseurl + 'customer/login/',{
            'username:': formData.username,
            'Password:': formData.password,
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

        setFormData({
            username: '',
            password: ''
          });
      };
    
    return (
    
    <div className= "container mt-4">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-8 col-12 offset-2">
                <div className="card">
                  <h4 className="card-header">Login</h4>
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                      
                      <div className="mb-3">
                        <label for="username" className="form-label">Username</label>
                        <input 
                        type="text"  
                        name="username" 
                        value={formData.username}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        className="form-control" 
                        id="username" 
                        aria-describedby="usernameHelp" />
                      
                      </div>
                       

                      <div className="mb-3">
                        <label for="pwd" className="form-label">Password</label>
                        <input 
                        type="password" 
                        name="password"
                        value={formData.password}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        className="form-control" 
                        id="pwd"/>
                      </div>
                     
                      <button  type="submit"  className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>

                  </div>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

I'm facing an issue that I need some assistance with. The problem I'm encountering is that when I send form data to the server, I'm unable to receive it correctly. Instead, the server is returning an empty dictionary. Is there anyone who can provide guidance and help me with this? If you have any suggestions or advice to offer, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: been long I used django but: if usoing rest framework...have you tried printing/using `request.data` instead??

Answer (score 1):

Try to get **request.body** instead of **request.POST**:

```
import json
@csrf_exempt
def customer_login(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    print(data)
    msg={
        'bool':True,
        "post":request.POST
    }
 
    return JsonResponse(msg)
```